How can I fix a broken wire in a junction box?
While replacing a light switch, the white wire is broken where it enters the box. I believe it was already damaged at that point because it broke very easily. This is in the master bedroom and goes into an outlet which is used to power a nightstand light (10 watts or so).
Any advice for fixing this? I tried to pull the wire, but it is very tight, and no slack is available.


This won't be simple because you have so little room to work, but trim back as much plastic sheathing as you can over the cable, (bundle of all the wires).
Get as much of the white wire as you can and strip the insulation back about 3/8 of an inch, ( aprox. 10MM )
Use a Wire lever connector to connect the old wire to a new piece of white wire of the same gauge. (About 7 inches (13cm.)
Now you are ready to install your new outlet.
Disclaimer:  I do not know if this is compliant with NEC exactly, but it is the most practical solution.
